# Laravel 5.5 issue in fetching data through eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The database table is : prefix_adminUsers and I have a model in **UserAdmin.php** as below:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserAdmin extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'adminUsers';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

When I tried to access the same by controller it show me the error:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder Object ( [query:protected] =>
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Object ( [connection] =>
>   Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection Object ( [pdo:protected] => PDO
>   Object

my **controller** is as follows:

```
use App\Model\UserAdmin;
$userRecord = UserAdmin::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
print_r($userRecord);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, you are printing the eloquent class [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html), used to build the queries to retrieve the model data, but it doesn't give you the results yet because you are missing `->get()` at the end.

Your code should look like:

```
use App\Model\UserAdmin;
$userRecord = UserAdmin::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
print_r($userRecord);
```

You can read more how to retrieve Models on the Laravel 5.5 [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-models).

> Since each Eloquent model serves as a query builder, you may
>   also add constraints to queries, **and then use the `get` method to
>   retrieve the results**.